# Mongoid where for boolean value not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using `'mongo', '1.6.2'` and `'mongoid', '2.4.11'`.
I have ProPlayer model, When I run in console.

```
irb(main):006:0> ProPlayer.first
=> #<ProPlayer _id: 508a5549d3966f02e7000001, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: "Adam", last_name: "Jones", batting_style: "R", image_thumbnail: "1.jpg", is_pro_player: true, team_id: BSON::ObjectId('508a550ad3966f02ce000012'), token_id: nil>
```

Here record with is_pro_player as true present but when I run where query, returns me zero records but actually there are 71 records present.

```
irb(main):008:0> ProPlayer.where(:is_pro_player=>true).to_a.size
=> 0
```

This query was working before but suddenly not working. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: What's in that record if you query from the Mongo console directly (thereby bypassing the Mongoid typecasts)?

Comment: @ ChrisHeald : query is working in mongo. returning correct records, problem is because of mongoid, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ProPlayer.where(:is_pro_player.exists => true, is_pro_player: true).count
```

Comment: Ok, can you please provide the JS hash of one matching document when doing the query in mongo console ? Use `findOne({ is_pro_player: true })` function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing type from "Boolean" to "Mongoid::Boolean", then it will start putting boolean values in the db as "true" and "false" instead of "1" and "0" and "where" conditions will start working again